# Invariant Violation: invalid prop 'fontSize' of type 'string' supplied to 'Stylesheet generated' expected 'number' - Styled Components RN

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

Not sure where I'm going wrong, I know React native doesn't support units but isn't styled-components taking care of that conversion. Every time I run it, it throws an error 'stylesheet generated value as a string, but expected is number'.
When I look into styled-components docs, this syntax seems fine.

```
const HomeContainer = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  background-color: hsl(202, 8%, 90%);
`;

const TaskWrapper = styled.View`
  padding-top: 5rem;
  padding-left: 1.2rem;
`;

const SectionTitle = styled.Text`
  color: hsl(0, 25%, 90%);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
`;

const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <HomeContainer theme={props.theme}>
      <TaskWrapper>
        <SectionTitle theme={props.theme}> Today's Tasks </SectionTitle
      </TaskWrapper>
    </HomeContainer>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

Error :

```
Running application on sdk_gphone_x86.

Invariant Violation: Invalid prop `fontSize` of type `string` supplied to `StyleSheet generated`, expected `number`.
StyleSheet generated: {
  "color": "hsl(0, 25%, 90%)",
  "fontSize": "1.5rem"
}

This error is located at:
    in StyledNativeComponent (created by Styled(Text))
    in Styled(Text) (at home.js:27)
```

Comment: Hi I think this github issue is similar to your question. Can you please look at this one? thanks https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2546

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't use relative units like `rem` or `em` in react-native. Rather you can use `px` value to define your fontSize and use the value as `Number`.

Your code may look like -

```js
const SectionTitle = styled.Text`
  color: hsl(0, 25%, 90%);
  font-size: 16;
`;
```

**Note:** I have assumed your `fontSize` value as `16px`.

Comment: That didn't work too, From my observations, I've seen numbers, rem/em are not working. However, using px resolved the issue. something like font-size:16px works magically! But styled components documentation uses rem and em too. couldn't figure out that issue.

Comment: That's weird! Your error is showing that the stylesheet is expecting `number`! Whatever, you can post your comment as an answer, if that's the working solution.